# Undefined reference to Class even though I compiled all cpp files

Tags: c++, g++

first of all I am kind of new to coding, so it might be that I just missed something really obvious. Still I would appreciate any help.

I created some header and some code files in one directory, namely "main.cpp","elements.cpp","queue.cpp", "elements.hpp" and "queue.hpp". In "main.cpp" I included both .hpp files.

Then I compiled: `g++ main.cpp elements.cpp queue.cpp`to get an executable file with all three .cpp files linked.
Still I get the following error message `/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccUjQcqj.o: in function main': main.cpp:(.text+0x33): undefined reference to Queue::Queue()'`.
Queue is a class declared in "queue.hpp".

Here is the code for "queue.hpp":

```
#include "elements.hpp"

class Queue{

Element Q[10];
int start;
int count;

void print(bool dir,int count);

public:

Queue(); //Standard Konstruktor Deklaration

void push(Element e);

void pop();

Element& top();

void print(bool dir=true);

int size();
};
```

Here is the code for "queue.cpp":

```
#include "elements.hpp" 
#include <iostream>


class Queue{

Element Q[10];
int start;
int count;

void print(bool dir,int count){ 
if(count>0 && dir==0){
Q[count-1].print();
print(dir,count-1);
}
if(count>0 && dir==1){
print(dir,count-1);
Q[count-1].print();
}
}

public:

Queue():start(0),count(0){}

void push(Element e){
if (count==10){
for(int i=0;i<9;i++){
Q[i]=Q[i+1];
}
Q[9]=e;
}
else{Q[start+count]=e;
count++;
}}

void pop(){
for(int i=0;i<9;i++){
Q[i]=Q[i+1];
}
count--;
}

Element& top(){
return Q[0];
}

void print(bool dir=true){
print(dir,count);
}

int size(){
return count;
}
};
```

I do not understand why there is an undefined reference here, since I included "queue.hpp" in main and the constructor in "queue.cpp" is also not missing.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Where is the implementation of this function? `Queue(); //Standard Konstruktor Deklaration`

Comment: There is no definiiton for Queue::Queue. try with Queue::Queue() = default;

Comment: Go through your `queue.cpp` source file. Is there a definition (implementation) of the `Queue` constructor?

Comment: Sry I did not include the queue.cpp file yet. I defined the constructor there, so there shouldnt be any issues. Also I get an undefined reference error for all class members that are used in main even if they are included and defined in a .cpp file.

Comment: You have *two different* and totally unrelated definitions of the `Queue` class! You might need to take a step back and refresh on whatever your tutorial, book or teacher have said about building projects with multiple source files. Begin by including `queue.hpp` in your `queue.cpp` file, and you will be getting lots of errors.

Comment: You have two declarations of the class Queue. The cpp class declares and defines own class Queue. You should read some of essential C++ books to learn C++. Learning C++ on Q/A sites is a bad practice.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help guys. Like I said in the beginning of the course I am new to coding and I missed this important part. I did not find my mistake, since I did not know what to look for.